# C++ - definition of (*this)

Tags: java, c++

I have a code written in c++, I have no idea what this code is supposed to do. I have tried to search in forums, but I'm still confused.
Can somebody please help me to define this code for me?

```
inline void normalize() {
       const float inv_length = 1.0f / get_length();
       (*this) *= inv_length;
}
```

The **(*this)** syntax is really confusing me, does it refer to return value?
If you have more time, can you please rewrite it in Java?

Comment: First of all, do you know what is "pointer" in C++?

Comment: "__(*this)__ syntax is really confused." Yes it is. It's confused as to what you are trying to do with it. (It's a joke)

Comment: @NickyC yes, just some fundamental theory about pointer in c++

Comment: @lloistborn What about the syntax of pointer?

Comment: @JClassic that function is in a class called vector2f, does "this" returning a constructor's value? or what? sorry, i have no idea

Comment: Calm down Iloistborn. It was a joke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is a pointer to the current object a member function is called on.

`*this` just dereferences that pointer, so it's a reference to that object.

---

**Rewritten to Java:**

```
void normalize() {
    final float inv_length = 1.0f / get_length();
    this.multiply(inv_length); // Since there is no operator overloading in Java, this had to be converted to a method.
    // Note that the "this." above is optional.
}
```

While the `this` keyword gives you a pointer in C++ (Because references were added to C++ later than `this`.), the same keyword gives you a reference in Java, as pointed out by [Nicky C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2486888/nicky-c).

Comment: That's not valid Java code. You can't assign anything to `this` in Java

Comment: @BluesSolo True, fixed that.

Comment: I think this answer need a sentence like "While `this` keyword gives you pointer in C++, the keyword gives you reference in Java" or something.

Comment: @NickyC Thanks, added that to the answer.

Answer (score -3):

(this) is a pointer, that is it stores the address of a variable. The asterix ( * ) before it indicates that this is a pointer.

```
(*this) *= inv_length;
```

is the same as

```
(*this) = (*this) * inv_length;
```

(*this) is the value of whatever (this) is pointing to

What your statement is doing is that it is multiplying the value stored in the pointer by inv_length.

Comment: No, `*` is not a pointer.

Comment: `*` in this context is the *dereference operator*, not a pointer. `this` is a pointer.

Comment: In my knowledge, is it correct to think that __*this__ is the object, while __this__ is the pointer?

Comment: @JClassic Yes, that's exactly the way to think about it.

Comment: @zenith Aha! Shame that's the only thing I know about c++ exclusive features :/

Comment: No, `(*this)` is not the value `this` is pointing to.

Comment: @NickyC please clarify?

Comment: @JClassic `(*this)` is a **reference** to the object `this` is pointing to.

Comment: @NickyC but why would the pointer differ from the reference? Is it because the reference allows you to alter and change the object, while the pointer merely indicates the position on the memory? I've always thought they were the same :/

Comment: @JClassic The difference is they are two distinct language features in C++.

Comment: @JClassic A reference is essentially the same as the object itself. You can you do all the same things with a reference as the real object. The difference is that the value of the original object is not copied when you use a reference.